# Possible to implement bit-wise rotation using analogue signal?

Tags: analog

Is it possible to implement the bit-wise rotation operation using an analogue signal following the below pattern? The design should not be implemented using an ADC-shifter-DAC model. This is for information solely, not for a practical circuit.

Input of 13 volts (representing 5-bits of 01101) -> Rotate left by 3 device -> Output of 11 volts (01011)

Comment: "bitwise rotation" only makes sense in the digital domain; any solution will necessarily use *some* sort of conversion.

Comment: Okay, I can understand that. Is it possible to implement a method of taking in the 13 volts and outputting 11 volts, taking in 17 volts and outputting 3 volts, etc? Thus avoiding the "bit-wise" business.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the input is 13.237 V? If you say "the same thing as if the input were 13.0 V", you're basically requiring a digitization of the input even if the coding scheme is multilevel rather than binary.

Comment: The "shifting" device should treat values within a range around even voltage levels as the same. ie, 12.7-13.3 V would be treated as 13.0 V. So some form of regulation and quantization would probably be required.

Comment: How about command? Will that be analog accurate?

Comment: Basically this question is "Can modulo arithmetic be done in the analogue domain"

Comment: What on earth is this for?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a scheme that meets the letter of your request. You said that ADC -> bit shift -> DAC is unacceptable, so you can do something like  ADC -> look-up-table -> analog mux instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7nYUJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor chain and comparators essentially form a *direct-conversion* ADC. The AND gates work out which is the "highest" of the comparators activated, and enable a corresponding NFET switch. Assume the output high level of the AND gate is higher than any of the required output voltages.

V1, V2, ... Vn, could be generated by whatever means you like. Another resistor divider chain would be possible (with the taps taken in the order corresponding to the bit-shift operation you want to do instead of in increasing order).

Depending what the load is, you might like to buffer the output.

Comment: Maybe call this "ADC + analog look-up-table" instead of ADC + look-up + mux.

Answer (score 0):

The logical rotation can be partially replaced by multiplication and division by 2.

A simple analog domain model would be non inverting amplifier with gain 2 - rotate left and voltage divider with equal resistors - rotate right.

The only problem I can't imagine how to solve in this model is the overflow - when one bit goes to the leftmost bit and then appears in the rightmost. So, this model is more like "shift" operation, not actually rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
x rot n = x >> n | x << (m-n)
```

`m` = word width in bits (constant; e.g. = 5)
`n` = number of bits to rotate (constant; e.g. = 3)

- Bitwise **shift right** is equivalent to integer division by powers of 2 (e.g. 8; which can be done easily in analog by a voltage divider; most difficult part if the intrinsic trucation, i.e. rounding to the next lower integer; if you need truncation depends on whether you allow output voltages between integer steps or not)
- Bitwise **shift left** is equivalent to integer multiplication by powers of 2 (e.g. 4; wich can easily be done in analog. EDIT: similar to the above point, in addition you need to "cut" something, i.e. a modulo 2^m operation is need).
- Bitwise **rotation** can be done by combing both operations. This combination can be achieved by adding both analog signals.

EDIT:
Truncation could be done by some diode oder Z-diode network.
Modulo could be done by subtracting a truncated signal from the original signal.

Comment: Okay. But how does one convert the voltage into a form usable in that algorithm?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Why convert? As the problem is stated the voltage already IS in this form.

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: What do you mean? OP gives example for input format: "Input of 13 volts (representing 5-bits of 01101)". This is given, i.e. not part of the problem.

Comment: "representing", not "represented as".

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: beeing a little less tight-lipped would immensely help to figure out what you mean.

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. If I multiply 11 volts by 2, and am expecting to get 6 volts because the "MSB" got lost, how do I implement that in the analog domain? Similarly, if I divide 5 volts by 2, I expect 2 volts, not 2.5.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: Yes, you are right. See my edited text for an outline how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, one could do an analog single-bit left shift by using a circuit which would multiply an input voltage by exactly two, checking whether it exceed a certain threshold, and subtracting that amount of voltage if it does.  For example, if a voltage is a quantity in the range 0 to 1 volt, one would end up subtracting a volt if the input was 0.5 volts or higher.  If the amount subtracted is reduced by whatever voltage is considered to be "one lsb", one the single-bit left shift can be turned into a single-bit left rotate.  That may be repeated to rotate a signal by other amounts.

In theory, one use this approach to yield an "infinite precision" ADC by simply shifting a signal left and observing the bits that fall off.  One could also do a "shift right from carry" by dividing a signal by two and adding half the full-scale value if there should be a carry in, and use that to yield an "infinite precision" DAC [note that the ADC would supply data MSB first, while the DAC would require data LSB first).  It's possible that such an approach might actually be practical for certain ADC or DAC applications, but imprecisions in the scaling or addition of signals would accumulate through successive operations, such that the resulting circuit would likely work less well than more conventional designs.  If an application would measure the imperfections and adapt itself accordingly, such compensation might make it possible to achieve performance that was competitive with other ADC/DAC implementations, but I'm unaware whether anyone has endeavored to do so.